# prove $x^2 = 4 c(y+c)$ is self orthogonal trajectory

Tags: geometry, ordinary-differential-equations, orthogonality

Can someone come up with a proof with this $$x^2 = 4 c(y+c)$$ to be self orthogonal?

I know in have to put $-dx/dy$ instead of $dy/dx$ but I cant solve it

Comment: What does self-orthogonal mean?

Comment: it is the orthonogal trajectory of it self @JohnMa

Comment: @JohnMa Every intersection between two curves with different $c$ values is orthogonal.

Comment: One can prove that using the reflection property of parabola.One hint is that all parabolas of the above form has the same focus.

Comment: maybe decrease the complexity of it a bit if one side is even so is the other ...

Comment: @Roddy MacPhee What do you mean by "one side is even" ?

Comment: I was just saying that one side has a factor of 4 therefore in the rationals at least the numerator of x would have to be even and hence you can factor out the factor of 4 on each side and reduce the equality. I'm probably just being stupid.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose there are two curves with parameters $c_1$ and $c_2$. Then at their points $(x,y)$ of intersection, $x^2 = 4c_1(y+c_1)$ and $x^2 = 4c_2 (y+c_2)$. These can be easily solved, giving $y = -c_1 - c_2$ and $x^2 = -4c_1c_2$.

For the curves to be orthogonal at a point, they must satisfy
$$
\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)_1\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)_2 = -1.
$$
Differentiating the defining equation with respect to $x$ gives $dy/dx = x/(2c)$, so we have
$$
\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)_1\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)_2 =\left(\frac{x}{2c_1}\right)\left(\frac{x}{2c_2}\right) = \frac{x^2}{4c_1c_2} =  -1,
$$
as desired.

Comment: The last equality is possible only if  $c_1$  and $c_2$ have opposite sign. This is why, in my solution, I have at once splitted the family of curves into 2 families.

Comment: Don't you think that something is strange in your last equality : $ \frac{x^2}{4c_1c_2} =  -1$ if $c_1c_2>0$ ? You would have a positive quantity on the LHS and an negative quantity on the RHS !

Comment: @JeanMarie All that has to be proven is that if the two curves intersect, then that intersection is orthogonal. Since there are no intersection points when $c_1c_2>0$, that equation holds.

Comment: Look at the graphic in my solution : the green parabolas for example are not orthogonal one to the other : they even have no common point.

Comment: As you like it. I think that you should have stressed this point.

Answer (score 2):

Let us split the unique family of curves (parabolas with $oy$ as symmetry axes) into two families. 
See figure below, borrowed to (http://xahlee.info/SpecialPlaneCurves_dir/ConicSections_dir/conicSections.html):

$$\tag{1}\begin{cases}F_c(x,y)&=&x^2-4c(y+c)&=&0 \ \text{with} \ c>0 \ \text{(green parabolas)}\\G_{c'}(x,y)&=&x^2+4c'(y-c')&=&0 \ \text{with} \ c'>0  \ \text{(purple parabolas)}\end{cases}$$

Solving system (1), it is easy to obtain the coordinates of generic intersection point(s) $I$ which are:

$$\tag{2}x=\pm \sqrt{4cc'}, \ \ y=c'-c.$$

It suffices to prove that the normal vectors at point(s) $I$ to the $F_c$ curve and to the  $G_{c'}$ curve (featured in black) are orthogonal.

It is easy because the normal vectors are given by the gradient operation :

$$\binom{\tfrac{\partial F_c}{\partial x}}{\tfrac{\partial F_c}{\partial y}}=\binom{\ \ 2x}{-4c} \ \ \text{and} \ \ \binom{\tfrac{\partial G_{c'}}{\partial x}}{\tfrac{\partial G_{c'}}{\partial y}}=\binom{2x}{4c'}$$

The dot product of these normal vectors,

$$4x^2-16cc',$$

is clearly $0$ when  $x=\pm \sqrt{2cc'}$ (abscissas of points $I$ (see (2))).

**Remarks:**

1) It can be shown that all these parabolas have a common focus: the origin.

2) These curves are connected to complex function $f(z)=\sqrt{z}$ : see for example [homofocal parabolas here](https://www.mathcurve.com/courbes2d.gb/orthogonale/orthogonale.shtml)

[image]

Comment: I have added a remark concerning a connection with complex functions theory.

Answer (score 1):

The ODE for the curves of the family $$ x^2= 4c(y+c)~~~(1) $$ Differentiating w.r.t. $x$, we get $2x=4cy'$ putting $c=\frac{x}{2y'}$ in (1) we get the ODE for (1)
$$x^2=\frac{2xy}{y'}+\frac{x^2}{y'^2} \implies x^2y'^2=2xyy'+x^2~~~(2)$$
Now if we change $y'$ to $-\frac{1}{y'}$ in (2), we get the ODE for the orthogonal trajectories to (1) as
$$\frac{x^2}{y'^2}=-\frac{2xy}{y'}+x^2  \implies x^2y'^2=2xyy'+x^2~~~(3)$$
Eq. (2) and (3) being identical, the self orthogonality of (1) is proved.